# Centering a Foundation "sign up" form

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

How can I center the following form so it is centered vertically?

```
 <form>
  <div class="row collapse">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
      <div class="row collapse postfix-round">
        <div class="small-9 columns">
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="small-3 columns">
          <a href="#" class="button postfix">Submit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Many thanks,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For center align to form use class `small-centered` or `large-centered` as per your need like :

```
    <div class="large-6 small-centered columns">
```

For vertically centered try this css to form:

```
form {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```